# vb.net string value merged to one

Tags: vb.net

I have a set of strings:

```
121010

121010

121011

121011
```

What I want to do is take all of the values and merge them together so I can get an output like this:

```
121010

121011
```

For instance, a listbox should search through that string and then give each result as a list item, if there was 400 "121010" values it would display as one value.

I have looked every where for a solution but I am now totally lost.

Any sort of reference would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add some code that you have tried so far?

Comment: Can you post sample input? your samples doesn't seems to be good enough to understand

Comment: So you have a single string or do you have a collection of strings (like a `List(Of String)`? If you have a collection, look into the `Distinct` extension method, or use a `HashSet` as collection.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. each line is a separate string. I will look into it, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)-extension-method:

```
Dim lst As New List(Of String)()
lst.Add("121010")
lst.Add("121011")
lst.Add("121010")
lst.Add("121011")
Dim distinctEntries = lst.Distinct()
```

As you are comparing strings, you might want to consider an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that also takes a comparer as input (in order to handle the casing of the letters in the way you want):

```
Dim distinctEntries = lst.Distinct(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

Comment: Thank you, the only problem is that the log, which contains the string, has over 50 000 lines. So that's where I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

> **Your question suppose to be `how to display unique list`**

Before adding to listbox,

- check whether item is added already
- If not, add it.

This is a basic coding style of check.

In the advance style of coding, you can use `Distinct()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use HashSet collection as below:

```
''String array.
    Dim a As String() = {"121010", "121010", "121011", "121011"}

    ' Create HashSet.
    Dim hash As HashSet(Of String) = New HashSet(Of String)(a)

    ' String array.
    a = hash.ToArray()
```

[HashSet VS Distinct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298679/whats-better-for-creating-distinct-data-structures-hashset-or-linqs-distinct).