# linq query group by in a list of strings

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I am very new to linq query with c#. I have a list of strings and I would like to get a new list or delete all double strings.

```
List<string> zipcodes = new List<string>();
zipcodes.Add("1234");
zipcodes.Add("1234");
zipcodes.Add("1234");
zipcodes.Add("4321");
zipcodes.Add("4321");

List<string> groupbyzipcodes =
(from zip in zipcodes
group zip by zip into newgroup
select newgroup.ToList());
```

> cannot implicitly convert type
>   `'System.collection.Generic.IEnumarable<System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'`
>   to `'System.collections.Generic.List<string>`. an explicit conversion
>   exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can also use the distinct keyword in LINQ:

```
var dedupedlist = zipcodes.Distinct().ToList();
```

For more see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348436(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: nice one! but where would this be used ?

Answer (score 5):

this is the most efficient way to remove duplicate values

```
var groupbyzipcodes = new HashSet<string>(zipcodes);
```

I already discussed that issue (`HashSet` vs `Distinct()`) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30366669/most-efficient-way-to-remove-duplicates-from-a-list)

Comment: An interesting read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298679/whats-better-for-creating-distinct-data-structures-hashset-or-linqs-distinct

Comment: Interesting, I would have thought that distinct would have been implemented in the most efficient way. Personally I feel that distinct is more readable, but it depends on the performance requirements of the application.

Answer (score 2):

There is a dedicated Linq method for this purpose:

```
var newList = zipCodes.Distinct().ToList();
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348436(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you only have a list of strings you can use distinct()

```
zipcodes.Distinct();
```

It will give you the uniq values of the list

Rgds

Answer (score 2):

As others have answered - there exists `Distinct` to get a distinct list from an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Your specific problem was that you have a `ToList()` inside the brackets, and it should be outside.

```
List<string> groupbyzipcodes =
(from zip in zipcodes
group zip by zip into newgroup
select newgroup.ToList())
```

should have been

```
List<string> groupbyzipcodes =
(from zip in zipcodes
group zip by zip into newgroup
select newgroup.Key).ToList();
```

Comment: Try running this code and you'll get `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Linq.IGrouping<string,string>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'`. You need to do `select newgroup.Key` to get this working.

Comment: @Chris - thanks, good spot.